# How can i share my google chrome extensions with people without upload on chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a google extension and i want to share it with people without uploading it on chrome web store and without letting people to know about the content code of the extension.
 What shall i do ???

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The only way you can let people have your Chrome Extension without uploading it to Web Store, is by sending them a .zip file, that they unpack and load in chrome://extensions.

I don't see why you won't want people to know about the content of the extension, and why you won't just upload it to the Web Store.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way, except the way Toke Raabjerg mentioned. (Involving developer mode)
Besides this, there is an option to upload the Extension and not list it on the store. With this option only people with the direct link can download your Extension.